# how to set django_settings_module environment variable

Tags: python, django, windows

Please help me on how to set django_settings_module environment variable. Where do I include the setting in the path? Here is the path I set for python: C:\Users\Freddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32;C:\Users\Freddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts. What prompted me to seek help is that in the command prompt I typed "django-admin" and I got the following message "note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured  before accessing settings"

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `django-admin` normally. Create your project with `django-admin startproject myproject`. Then use `manage.py`, which takes care of setting the environment variable for you.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair. But I used manage.py and I got a message that " manage.py is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. Please pardon me,I am very new in python and django.

Comment: You need to switch to the project directory that contains `manage.py`, e.g. `cd myproject`. Then try `python manage.py`. If you are new to Django, then I suggest you follow a tutorial, e.g. https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_start_project/#your-first-django-project

Comment: Thanks so much Alasdair ,it works.